# Crash in UIKit related to WebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have a random crash in UIKit that happend a couple of times already.

It crashes with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000d`

```
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x30e08f46 objc_msgSend + 5
1  UIKit                          0x26d1790d -[_UIWebViewScrollViewDelegateForwarder forwardInvocation:] + 140
2  CoreFoundation                 0x23654def ___forwarding___ + 354
3  CoreFoundation                 0x23586df8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 24
4  UIKit                          0x26b5a6fd -[UIScrollView _getDelegateZoomView] + 84
5  UIKit                          0x26b5a635 -[UIScrollView _zoomScaleFromPresentationLayer:] + 24
6  UIKit                          0x26b5a5ed -[UIWebDocumentView _zoomedDocumentScale] + 64
7  UIKit                          0x26b5a13d -[UIWebDocumentView _layoutRectForFixedPositionObjects] + 104
8  UIKit                          0x26b59f97 -[UIWebDocumentView _updateFixedPositionedObjectsLayoutRectUsingWebThread:synchronize:] + 38
9  UIKit                          0x26b5c3e5 -[UIWebDocumentView _updateFixedPositioningObjectsLayoutAfterScroll] + 28
10 UIKit                          0x26b5c3c1 -[UIWebBrowserView _updateFixedPositioningObjectsLayoutAfterScroll] + 56
11 CoreFoundation                 0x2360a281 __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 12
12 CoreFoundation                 0x2356652d _CFXNotificationPost + 1784
13 Foundation                     0x24296189 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 72
14 UIKit                          0x27171dd7 -[UIInputWindowController postEndNotifications:withInfo:] + 554
15 UIKit                          0x271732ed __77-[UIInputWindowController moveFromPlacement:toPlacement:starting:completion:]_block_invoke595 + 368
16 UIKit                          0x26b44b05 -[UIViewAnimationBlockDelegate _didEndBlockAnimation:finished:context:] + 308
17 UIKit                          0x26b4471d -[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:] + 184
18 UIKit                          0x26b4462f -[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:] + 66
19 QuartzCore                     0x2653d2d9 CA::Layer::run_animation_callbacks(void*) + 236
20 libdispatch.dylib              0x3135c7a7 _dispatch_client_callout + 22
21 libdispatch.dylib              0x3135ffa3 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 718
22 CoreFoundation                 0x236179d1 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 8
23 CoreFoundation                 0x236160d1 __CFRunLoopRun + 1512
24 CoreFoundation                 0x23564211 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 476
25 CoreFoundation                 0x23564023 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
26 GraphicsServices               0x2a95d0a9 GSEventRunModal + 136
27 UIKit                          0x26b701d1 UIApplicationMain + 1440
28 MY_PROJECT                     0x000842cf main (main.m:16)
```

It looks like it is related to UIWebView, but I have no clue what happened - any help is appreciated
The crash seems to be known in China ...

Comment: Check your observers, maybe need to remove...

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I did that and really found some issues. Now I need to wait if the crash happens again in the next days ...

Comment: @dogsgod I am also facing similar issue any luck with this ?

Comment: It's resolved, please see my answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @ NilsHolgerson I had a some issues with notifications.
The most probable reason was a notification that was not properly removed and that did retain a ViewController that was detached otherwise:

```
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil queue:nil usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
                [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];
                ...
```

The solution looks as follows:

```
__weak typeof(self) weakself = self;
__block NSObject *reference = [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil queue:nil usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
                [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:reference];
                ...
```

Comment: hi i have a same issue where to put above code in Viewcontroller class

Comment: the second code block is replacing the creation of the notification watcher and already contains the deletion of the watcher.

Comment: i have multiple webview in uitableview so app crash randomly where to put  your code like viewdidload or viewwillappear ? please give me reply thanks

Comment: Please raise a question here on SO and provide some details. I'm unable to help without any code ...

Answer (score 1):

The deeply reason of this issues is: **Container ViewController has been released when webView doing some animations.**

So the directly solution is **set webView's delegate to nil when ViewControllers dealloc**.

Of course if you release VC appropriately as @dogsgod do is also a solution.